# Why isn't the following import working?

Tags: go, command-line-interface

Why the following works

```
package main

import (
    "os"

    cli "github.com/urfave/cli"
)

func main() {
    cli.NewApp().Run(os.Args)
}
```

but when I change the `cli` import to following as suggested in https://github.com/urfave/cli

```
import (
        "os"

        cli "gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v2"
    )
```

It gives this error `undefined: cli.NewApp`

Comment: Whoever down voted this, care to leave a comment?

Comment: The answer is in the [docs](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v2)

Comment: @Clive can you point me to the specific location please. I was reading the docs on github

Comment: The first code example in the link isn't setting off any alarm bells when you compare it to your existing code?

Comment: @Clive sorry no! I am following examples listed here https://github.com/urfave/cli

Comment: That would be the problem :) you've imported a different version, now you need to look at _that version's_ docs, no? I linked to them in the first comment, maybe you didn't see it? The first code example uses `App` instead of `NewApp`

Comment: @clive My intuition was that the github.com/urfave/cli will point to the latest version.  Seems like its pointing to the stable version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

v2 of the package has no NewApp() method.

Answer (score 1):

As it doesn't initialize with defaults the example below is not exactly the same as the NewApp() method, but you can try something like this, if you want to give v2 of the package a try.

```
package main

import (
    "os"

    cli "gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v2"
)

func main() {
    (&cli.App{}).Run(os.Args)
}
```

Make sure to read the README.md file contained in the v2 package, as it also contains updated instructions and examples.